# Как создать шаблон в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, шаблоны, freemarker

В файле template есть данные

```
  <parameter id="className"
name="Fragment Name"
type="string"
constraints="class|unique|nonempty"
default="Fragment"
help="input Fragment class"/>
```

Я хочу чтобы после ввода названия, например: `MainActivity`.  после нажатия на кнопку OK урезалось имя в параметре `className` и стало просто `Main`.

Как это можно сделать? на сайте FreeMarker не нашел инфу нужную.

Comment: то есть вы хотите напечатать на клавиатуре Main**Activity** и чтобы после этого осталось только Main. Не будет ли всем проще, если вы не будете допечатывать Activity, а сразу наберете только Main или я не понял глубокий смысл такого шаблона

Comment: Да просто в будущем будет путаница большая. Так как стандартные шаблоны создаются если пишешь Activity  значит и с Activity  создадутся.... То что вы предложили это поможет, но это больше временное решение....